# How to check why file is not opened?

Tags: c++, file, io

```
std::ifstream fin;
fin.open("file.txt", std::ios::in);
std::cout << fin.is_open();
```

This code prints `false` so the file is not opened. How to check why is it. Maybe get error message from `fin` object? I am guessing the reason is that the file is opened already for writing. But I want to open it for reading. Is it possible to open a file both for reading and writing.?

I am using linux. With `strerror(errno)` I get the error No such file or directory but I the file exists. Maybe the error is because it is opened already using other object?
It is already opened using C API, therefore `fin` cant open it. How can I open file which already is opened?

Comment: In C++ I would use the [make_error_code](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/io_errc/make_error_code/) function.

Comment: What is the type of `fin`?

Comment: The file does no exist where you expect it. Check the location or use `std::ifstream fin("file.txt")` to create it first.

Comment: The file exists indeed. But it is already opened using C API, therefore fin cant open it. How can I open file which already is opend

Comment: Make `fin` a global `std::fstream` and then you would have control over it to open/close it whenever you want.

Comment: Unix systems (and Linux) allow a file to be opened multiple times, so that isn't the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard specifies that there is a preprocessor symbol
`errno`, which expands to something which references a (thread
local) `int`, in which system functions are expected to put an
extended error code.  It also defines a function `strerror`,
which allow recovering a `char const*` with a text message,
given this number (but unlike `errno`, that function is not
guaranteed to be thread safe).

The standard does *not* place any requirements on `filebuf` to
use `errno`, at least not in the case of `open`, but in
practice, `filebuf` will invoke lower level functions which will
(hopefully) use `errno`.  (This is required by Posix, where all
of the system calls set `errno` in case of error.  I'm less sure
about Windows.)

As for bi-directional access: it's probably a bad idea, but...
`filebuf` is always potentially bidirectional, but `ifstream`
won't define any `<<` operators, and `ofstream` won't define any
`>>` operators, so you might want to use `std::fstream`.  If you
want to be able to seek, you'll also want to open the file in
binary mode; otherwise, you can only seek to places you've been
to before, and memorized the position.  If you want to read what
you've just written, a better solution would be to close the
output, then open it for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Answer Q#1: `errno` and also `GetLastError()` hold the last error information. For getting the string message for the error use: `strerrno(errno)`.

Answer Q#2: To open it for both read/write you need to use a `fstream` (not `ostream` or `istream`) class and set the open mode to `std::ios::in | std::ios::out`.

Comment: +1 for #2, -1 for #1: it's C++ (for errno), he's using C++ streams, he didn't say it's Windows only (for GetLastError).

Comment: Yes, you are indeed right. I sometimes forget not everybody's using Windows :)

Comment: -1 You cannot use `GetLastError` here, even on Windows. You don't know what other API calls have been made since the one that failed. You cannot mix error models like that. You can use `GetLastError` if a call to `CreateFile` fails. I'm also dubious as to whether or not `errno` is meaningful here. From what I can tell, `ifstream` makes no promises about the state of `errno` upon failure. Or am I missing something?

Comment: OK I am using linux. with `strerrno(errno)` I get the error `No such file or directory` but I the file exists. Maybe the error is because it is opened already using other object

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The C++ standard says nothing about this, but it does define `filebuf::open` in terms of `fopen`, and refer to the C standard.  The C standard doesn't really document anything either, but it has been generally acknowledged that the intent is for failing library functions to use `errno` to say why.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you should use fstream instead of ifstream or ofstream. please refer to link below:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: That's a very poor presentation.